# Broadcasting an INSTALL_REFERRER Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-analytics

The problem is that i cannot get referrer uri in my receiver.
In manifest file i have something like:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="app.InstallReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Adb broadcast command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER 
-n app/app.InstallReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

In InstallReceiver class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Uri uri = intent.getData(); // getting uri is null
   String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
   // referrer is only contains "utm_source=testSource" and no more
```

So the question is where the full referrer and what's wrong with my intent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `intent` broadcast referrer value doesn't get set correctly. The value will be escaped once by the shell calling `adb` and one more time by the Android shell executing the broadcast command. Try sending the request like this:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n app/app.InstallReceiver --es referrer "'utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign'"
```

Note the double escaping - once with single quote ' and once with double quotes "

Comment: That's right, i've already accomplished this but forgot to answer myself.

Comment: This solution solved me after a lot of search! My problem was i'm not using double escaping. So i wasn't receiving all params.